# Program with inline assembly segfaults unless prefixed with function call

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void my_func(char *text) {
    //printf("hello again\n");
    __asm__(
        "push %%ebp\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%ebx\n\t"
        "push %%ebx\n\t"
        "call strlen\n\t"
        "movb (%%ebx), %%al" 
    : : "r"(text));
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        my_func("hello");
}
```

Test run:

```
$ gcc -v
(...)
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why does my program crash unless I uncomment the `printf` call?

Here's the disassembly for the two functions:

OK version (w/ `printf` call):

```
0804844d <my_func>:
 804844d:   55                      push   %ebp
 804844e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048450:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 8048453:   c7 04 24 30 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048530,(%esp)
 804845a:   e8 b1 fe ff ff          call   8048310 <puts@plt>
 804845f:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048462:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
 8048464:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048465:   e8 c6 fe ff ff          call   8048330 <strlen@plt>
 804846a:   8a 03                   mov    (%ebx),%al
 804846c:   c9                      leave  
 804846d:   c3                      ret
```

Crashing version (no `printf` call):

```
 0804841d <my_func>:
 804841d:   55                      push   %ebp
 804841e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048420:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048423:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
 8048425:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048426:   e8 d5 fe ff ff          call   8048300 <strlen@plt>
 804842b:   8a 03                   mov    (%ebx),%al
 804842d:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 804842e:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Are you pushing all the registers to the stack first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> "push %%ebx\n\t"
> "call strlen\n\t"
> ```

You `PUSH` something on the stack. Who do you expect to `POP` that something off the stack (clean up your call parameter)?

Linux uses "[caller cleanup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up)" calling convention, and by not cleaning up the call stack, you are making `my_func` return to a bogus address (which causes `SIGSEGV`).

Comment: Huh, I was under the impression the callee would cleanup. Thanks!